# 2D array is displaying incorrectly

Tags: c#, arrays

So what I need to do is take these two random arrays and subtract them from watch other, that isn't the issue should be easy.

My issue is that its displaying the arrays one number on each line, when I need it to display a 3x3 array.

Here is my code.

```
Random random = new Random();

int[,] newarray = new int[3, 3];
int[,] newarray1 = new int[3, 3];
int[,] newarray2 = new int[3, 3];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        newarray[i, j] = random.Next(-10, 10);
        Console.WriteLine(newarray[i,j] + " ");
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        newarray1[i, j] = random.Next(-10, 10);
        Console.WriteLine(newarray1[i, j] + " ");
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        newarray2[i, j] = newarray[i, j] - newarray1[i, j];
        Console.WriteLine(newarray2[i, j] + " ");
    }
}




Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:[eachlineisanewnumber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rekgI.jpg)

[image]

And changing `writeline` to write just puts it all on one line, instead of individual lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there, just use `Write` to append and `WriteLine` for a new line

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        newarray[i, j] = random.Next(-10, 10);
        Console.Write(newarray[i,j] + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

---

[Console.Write Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=netcore-3.1)

> Writes the text representation of the specified value or values to the
> standard output stream.

[Console.WriteLine Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netcore-3.1)

> Writes the specified data, followed by the current line terminator, to
> the standard output stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple way to print in matrix form using for loops.

```
int[,] arr = new int[3, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4,5,6}, { 7,8,9}};

int rows = arr.GetLength(0);
int columns = arr.GetLength(1);

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", arr[i, j]));
    }
    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Print every array as a matrix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");
    }
    Console.Write("\n");
}
```